# Struct variables not saved

Tags: go

I'm not sure why my arraylist isn't working as expected.

Here is my **ArrayList**

```
package main

// ArrayList in Go
type ArrayList struct {
    backingArray []string
    size         int
}

const initialCapacity int = 10

// NewArrayList constructor for ArrayList
func NewArrayList() *ArrayList {
    return &ArrayList{make([]string, initialCapacity), 0}
}

// AddAtIndex given by the user
func (a ArrayList) AddAtIndex(index int, data string) (bool, error) {
    if &data == nil || len(data) == 0 {
        return false, errors.New("Must enter data to delete")
    }
    if index < 0 || index > a.size {
        return false, errors.New("Invalid index")
    }
    arrLen := len(a.backingArray)
    if index == a.size && a.size < arrLen {
        a.backingArray[index] = data
        a.size++
        fmt.Println("Inside ArrayList: Size is ", a.size)
        return true, nil
    }
    if arrLen == a.size {
        arrLen *= 2
    }
    newBackingArray := make([]string, arrLen)
    for x, y := 0, 0; x < a.size; x++ {
        if x == index {
            y++
        }
        newBackingArray[y] = a.backingArray[x]
        y++
    }
    newBackingArray[index] = data
    a.backingArray = newBackingArray
    a.size++
    return true, nil
}
```

Here is my **main** function that makes ArrayList

```
func main() {
    a := NewArrayList()
    fmt.Println(a.AddAtIndex(0, "Brian"))
    fmt.Println("Outisde ArrayList: Size is ", a.GetSize())
}
```

I was expecting that after adding "Brian" at index 0, the size would update to 1 from 0.
However, the output shows

```
Inside ArrayList: Size is  1
true <nil>
Outisde ArrayList: Size is  0
```

Why isn't my size being updated?

Comment: Because you pass the ArrayList by value and not by reference. You need `func (a *ArrayList)AddAtIndex(...) { ...}`. I'm sure this must be a duplicate question.

Comment: Also, I note that you test `&data==nil`. This can never be true.

Comment: use a [pointer receiver](https://tour.golang.org/methods/4), see this example https://play.golang.org/p/ZmHDk8L6Ei9

Comment: Wow thank you so much for the answers! People on StackOverflow are so helpful. I will study more about the pointers :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you pass `ArrayList` instance by value, that's why it's being updated inside the `AddAtIndex` method, but not outside.
Try updating `AddAtIndex` method signature to the following, so that it accepts a reference to `ArrayList` instance (notice usage of * symbol):

```
func (a *ArrayList) AddAtIndex(index int, data string) (bool, error) {...}
```